# How should I have better asked this meta question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta

I asked this question on the meta site: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291697

Perhaps the wording was too accusatory, which was not my intention.

I was after the reasons behind going against what appeared to be the popular vote for a feature request. As it happened, the comments touched on this subject, but I feel the content was rather limited, as is often the case in comments.

How should I have asked it to avoid it being marked as a duplicate of the feature request in question? Was it indeed a duplicate?

Apologies if this is deemed a duplicate - I am aware of questions with similar titles. I would however have thought that the subject matter to such questions was unique.

Comment: A meta question asking about how to improve a different meta question.  That's so ....

Comment: ...RAVEN. THAT'S SO RAVEN.

Answer (score 14):

"Why hasn't this been implemented" type questions have about a 0% chance of being answered meaningfully, plus you're not really bringing anything new to the table that would change the discussion.

I guess that's the main reason behind the downvotes and the closing.

Questions that reference older feature requests but add a new, original aspect to them that is important enough to warrant a separate discussion are usually much better received.

However, even those may also get downvoted into oblivion if people disagree with what is being requested. That is normal on Meta and nothing to be too worried about.

Comment: Thanks. I agree my question was probably not a good one. I am slightly concerned by your last statement, as I would have thought it was a misuse of downvoting - I was under the impression it should only be used if the question is a poor *question* rather than a poor *idea*. Am I wrong?

Comment: @enigma on Meta, things are different sometimes. Downvotes can mean disagreement with a feature request.